# Fetch doesn't retrieve data

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, insomnia

I am currently building a login form which will be using a restAPI for the registration/Auth but I'm receiving a 401 error when using fetch to test the retrieved data.

```
console.log(fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/'), {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})

    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Please show code or explain what you are doing in your backend side.  Typically you should not use GET mehotd for authentications.

Comment: `401` mean you are not authorized.

Comment: So the problem is that I've got while trying to fetch the data from the API, after running Docker and testing the API (Which is correctly working), when I'm trying to retrieve the data of the default user-provided I'm getting a 401 error in my console.
Please let me know if I am missing something, I am currently stuck since a while.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. Please include a [mcve] in the question.